# Parse HTML into consisting tags

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to do various operations based on tag difference. How can I parse them in such a way that I can create separate groups for them?
I used query selectors but it is leading to unwanted complications as it is affecting my angular app structure. I want to differentiate it in the API only.

Comment: Can you expand on what you are ultimately trying to do? It is unclear in the question what you are attempting to accomplish. Also, if you can supply some sample code of what you have attempted, it can help to show what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm separating HTML coming from API a string into its consisting tags so that I can change them as required because I'm positioning them in an app using ionic and Each and every tag has to be processed in a different. Like I have to add  functionality where I can create a playlist of all the audio tags coming from the API